# Why vertices number increased when importing .STL file

Tags: export, import

I import a .STL `Import[*.st,"VertexData"]` file on mathematica and I remark that the number of vertices is increased comparing to the number given by Blender. However, the number of polygons is the same in both cases.
here is an example of [.stl](http://www.megafileupload.com/e1il/model.stl) file.

**Blender:**

[image: Blender]

**Mathematica:**

[image: Mathematica]

I am running mathematica 10.2 on Mac OS X.

[image]

---

The problem is do to Mathematica 10.2.0 on Mac OS X. I tried the same program on linux using Mathematica 10.0 and I get the right result. In addition I tried Mathematica 10.1.0.0 on Mac os x and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Statistics from info panel of Blender:
   Verts: 14,444 Faces: 28,796
2. Results from Mathematica:
   [image]
3. As shown in the image below, the STL file has such a structure that a facet element brings with 3 vertexes. 28796 "facet"s and 86388 "vertex"s are counted in total. Two lines coloured in yellow shows there exists repetitive vertexes and it seems that Mathematica is able to merge them while importing. I guess the problem you got is caused by the computational precision error. Your system somehow failed to distinguish some repetitive vertexes.

[image]

Comment: I download the attached file and I executed the same function as in your answer and I get different results for the vertices.

Comment: You are write. I think that there are a lot of vertex that repeated. So, I have used Union[] to get avoid the them and finally I get 14444 vertices